# Python import error when importing from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following files inside a package called `users`:

file `__init__.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .views import UserDetails, UserList

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

file `models.py`:

```
from users import db

class User(db.Model):
    pass
```

and file `views.py`:

```
from .models import User
from users import db

#code
```

But the following Import exception had occurred:

```
Error: While importing "users", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/microservices/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/www/microservices/Flask_Microservices/users/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .views import UserDetails, UserList
  File "/var/www/microservices/Flask_Microservices/users/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import User
  File "/var/www/microservices/Flask_Microservices/users/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from users import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

Any idea about what is wrong in my imports?

Comment: thank you, no unfortunately, views also use db. @00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess. Try to move

`from .views import UserDetails, UserList`

under `db = SQLAlchemy()` so it looks like

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

from .views import UserDetails, UserList
```

when you execute import from views it tries to import db from **init**.py in views.py file. It is not present yet so error occurs. At least I think so.